# Converting from Mathml to SVG using MathJax fails

Tags: javascript, html, svg, mathjax, mathml

I'm using [MathJax-2.6.1](https://stash.aggregion.com/projects/BCK/repos/bundle-service-js/browse/src/web/data/epub/scripts/mathjax/MathJax.js?at=1.2.2) with phantomJS by injecting the MathJax.js file (that I have in my local) to convert MathML into SVG. It works for normal MathML with simple semantics and annotation. But for the below MathML, it fails with:

> Error parsing MathML: error on line 41 at column 52: Opening and ending tag mismatch: img line 0 and m:annotation-XML**

I have tried injecting mml3.js and content-mathml.js (both v2.7.5) from my local. Still, I'm getting the same error. The order of injection is:-
MathJax.js - mml3.js - content-mathml.js

```
<html
xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<m:math
    xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <m:semantics>
        <m:mrow>
            <m:mrow>
                <m:mo>(</m:mo>
                <m:mrow>
                    <m:msup>
                        <m:mn>1</m:mn>
                        <m:mn>5</m:mn>
                    </m:msup>
                    <m:mo>+</m:mo>
                    <m:msup>
                        <m:mn>6</m:mn>
                        <m:mn>21</m:mn>
                    </m:msup>
                    <m:mo>+</m:mo>
                    <m:msup>
                        <m:mn>7</m:mn>
                        <m:mn>2</m:mn>
                    </m:msup>
                    <m:mo>+</m:mo>
                    <m:msup>
                        <m:mn>4</m:mn>
                        <m:mn>6</m:mn>
                    </m:msup>
                    <m:mo>+</m:mo>
                    <m:msup>
                        <m:mn>9</m:mn>
                        <m:mn>4</m:mn>
                    </m:msup>
                </m:mrow>
                <m:mo>)</m:mo>
            </m:mrow>
            <m:mo>&#x00F7;</m:mo>
            <m:mn>5</m:mn>
            <m:mo>=</m:mo>
            <m:mn>51</m:mn>
        </m:mrow>
        <m:annotation-xml encoding="application/xhtml+xml">
            <img src="equation.png" />
        </m:annotation-xml>
    </m:semantics>
</m:math>
</html>
```

But when I open the same after adding `src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=MML_SVG"`
in the browser(Mozilla Firefox) it shows in SVG. Need help on how can I convert this into SVG(Should work for all types of annotations) or any other method I can follow. I'm using javascript.

Comment: [Works](https://jsfiddle.net/vfy2hoq5/)

Comment: You should consider moving to something besides [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) as [development has been suspended](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344). [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) is a good alternative.